# How do I get my transformer model to produce an output

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, transformer-model, multihead-attention

I generated and trained a transformer model Using the following code

```
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.utils.data as data
import math
import pandas as pd
import tiktoken
import copy
import os

#todo fix cuda dependency later

class MultiHeadAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads):
        super(MultiHeadAttention, self).__init__()
        assert d_model % num_heads == 0, "d_model must be divisible by num_heads"
        
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.d_k = d_model // num_heads
        
        self.W_q = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
        self.W_k = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
        self.W_v = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
        self.W_o = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
        
    def scaled_dot_product_attention(self, Q, K, V, mask=None):
        attn_scores = torch.matmul(Q, K.transpose(-2, -1)) / math.sqrt(self.d_k)
        if mask is not None:
            attn_scores = attn_scores.masked_fill(mask == 0, -1e9)
        attn_probs = torch.softmax(attn_scores, dim=-1)
        output = torch.matmul(attn_probs, V)
        return output
        
    def split_heads(self, x):
        batch_size, seq_length, d_model = x.size()
        return x.view(batch_size, seq_length, self.num_heads, self.d_k).transpose(1, 2)
        
    def combine_heads(self, x):
        batch_size, _, seq_length, d_k = x.size()
        return x.transpose(1, 2).contiguous().view(batch_size, seq_length, self.d_model)
        
    def forward(self, Q, K, V, mask=None):
        Q = self.split_heads(self.W_q(Q))
        K = self.split_heads(self.W_k(K))
        V = self.split_heads(self.W_v(V))
        
        attn_output = self.scaled_dot_product_attention(Q, K, V, mask)
        output = self.W_o(self.combine_heads(attn_output))
        return output
    
class PositionWiseFeedForward(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, d_ff):
        super(PositionWiseFeedForward, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(d_model, d_ff)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(d_ff, d_model)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.fc2(self.relu(self.fc1(x)))
    
class PositionalEncoding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, max_seq_length):
        super(PositionalEncoding, self).__init__()
        
        pe = torch.zeros(max_seq_length, d_model)
        position = torch.arange(0, max_seq_length, dtype=torch.float).unsqueeze(1)
        div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0, d_model, 2).float() * -(math.log(10000.0) / d_model))
        
        pe[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(position * div_term)
        pe[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)
        
        self.register_buffer('pe', pe.unsqueeze(0))
        
    def forward(self, x):
        return x + self.pe[:, :x.size(1)]
    
class EncoderLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads, d_ff, dropout):
        super(EncoderLayer, self).__init__()
        self.self_attn = MultiHeadAttention(d_model, num_heads)
        self.feed_forward = PositionWiseFeedForward(d_model, d_ff)
        self.norm1 = nn.LayerNorm(d_model)
        self.norm2 = nn.LayerNorm(d_model)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        
    def forward(self, x, mask):
        attn_output = self.self_attn(x, x, x, mask)
        x = self.norm1(x + self.dropout(attn_output))
        ff_output = self.feed_forward(x)
        x = self.norm2(x + self.dropout(ff_output))
        return x
    
class DecoderLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads, d_ff, dropout):
        super(DecoderLayer, self).__init__()
        self.self_attn = MultiHeadAttention(d_model, num_heads)
        self.cross_attn = MultiHeadAttention(d_model, num_heads)
        self.feed_forward = PositionWiseFeedForward(d_model, d_ff)
        self.norm1 = nn.LayerNorm(d_model)
        self.norm2 = nn.LayerNorm(d_model)
        self.norm3 = nn.LayerNorm(d_model)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        
    def forward(self, x, enc_output, src_mask, tgt_mask):
        attn_output = self.self_attn(x, x, x, tgt_mask)
        x = self.norm1(x + self.dropout(attn_output))
        attn_output = self.cross_attn(x, enc_output, enc_output, src_mask)
        x = self.norm2(x + self.dropout(attn_output))
        ff_output = self.feed_forward(x)
        x = self.norm3(x + self.dropout(ff_output))
        return x
    
class Transformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, src_vocab_size, tgt_vocab_size, d_model, num_heads, num_layers, d_ff, max_seq_length, dropout):
        super(Transformer, self).__init__()
        self.encoder_embedding = nn.Embedding(src_vocab_size, d_model)
        self.decoder_embedding = nn.Embedding(tgt_vocab_size, d_model)
        self.positional_encoding = PositionalEncoding(d_model, max_seq_length)

        self.encoder_layers = nn.ModuleList([EncoderLayer(d_model, num_heads, d_ff, dropout) for _ in range(num_layers)])
        self.decoder_layers = nn.ModuleList([DecoderLayer(d_model, num_heads, d_ff, dropout) for _ in range(num_layers)])

        self.fc = nn.Linear(d_model, tgt_vocab_size)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def generate_mask(self, src, tgt):
        src_mask = (src != 0).unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(2)
        tgt_mask = (tgt != 0).unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(3)
        seq_length = tgt.size(1)

        nopeak_mask = (1 - torch.triu(torch.ones(1, seq_length, seq_length), diagonal=1)).bool().to('cuda')
        tgt_mask = tgt_mask.to('cuda') & nopeak_mask.to('cuda')
        return src_mask, tgt_mask

    def forward(self, src, tgt):
        src_mask, tgt_mask = self.generate_mask(src.to('cuda'), tgt.to('cuda'))
        src_embedded = self.dropout(self.positional_encoding(self.encoder_embedding(src)))
        tgt_embedded = self.dropout(self.positional_encoding(self.decoder_embedding(tgt)))

        enc_output = src_embedded
        for enc_layer in self.encoder_layers:
            enc_output = enc_layer(enc_output, src_mask)

        
        dec_output = tgt_embedded
        for dec_layer in self.decoder_layers:
            dec_output = dec_layer(dec_output, enc_output, src_mask, tgt_mask)

        output = self.fc(dec_output)
        return output
    
src_vocab_size = 100160
tgt_vocab_size = 79258
d_model = 50
num_heads = 5
num_layers = 3
d_ff = 2048
max_seq_length = 100
dropout = 0.1

transformer = Transformer(src_vocab_size, tgt_vocab_size, d_model, num_heads, num_layers, d_ff, max_seq_length, dropout)
transformer.to('cuda')

enctype = "cl100k_base"
encoding = tiktoken.get_encoding(enctype)
df = pd.read_csv('filepath', sep='\t', header = None)
df.columns = ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4']
df['Column2'] = df['Column2'].str.cat(df['Column3'], sep=' ', na_rep='')
#print(df.iloc[886, 0])
#print(df.iloc[886, 1])
#print(df.iloc[886, 2])
#src_data = torch.randint(1, 50, (64, 50))
#print(src_data)
source_list = [(encoding.encode(text)) for text in df['Column1']]
trgt_list = [(encoding.encode(text)) for text in df['Column2']]


source_tensors = []

for sublist in source_list:
    temptensor = torch.tensor(sublist[:16])  # Truncate sublist to length 16
    temptensor.to('cuda')
    if len(temptensor) < 16:
        padded_tensor = torch.zeros(16)  # Create a tensor of zeros
        padded_tensor.to('cuda')
        padded_tensor[:len(temptensor)] = temptensor  # Copy sublist elements into the padded tensor
        temptensor = padded_tensor
    source_tensors.append(temptensor)
    
    
target_tensors = []

for slis in trgt_list:
    temporarytens = torch.tensor(slis[:16])  # Truncate sublist to length 16
    temporarytens.to('cuda')
    if len(temporarytens) < 16:
        padded_tensy = torch.zeros(16)  # Create a tensor of zeros
        padded_tensy.to('cuda')
        padded_tensy[:len(temporarytens)] = temporarytens  # Copy sublist elements into the padded tensor
        temporarytens = padded_tensy
    target_tensors.append(temporarytens)
    
    
print (torch.cat(source_tensors).reshape(41316, 16))
print (torch.cat(target_tensors).reshape(41316, 16))
src_data = (torch.cat(source_tensors).reshape(41316, 16)).long()
tgt_data = (torch.cat(target_tensors).reshape(41316, 16)).long()
src_data = src_data.to('cuda')
tgt_data = tgt_data.to('cuda')

transformer = Transformer(src_vocab_size, tgt_vocab_size, d_model, num_heads, num_layers, d_ff, max_seq_length, dropout)

transformer.to('cuda')


criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(ignore_index=0)
optimizer = optim.Adam(transformer.parameters(), lr=0.0001, betas=(0.9, 0.98), eps=1e-9)

transformer.train()

# Define the batch size and number of splits
batch_size = 64
num_splits = math.ceil(src_data.shape[0] / batch_size)
best_loss = float('inf')

num_epochs = 70  # Set the desired number of epochs

with TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
    best_model_params_path = os.path.join(tempdir, "best_model_params.pt")
    
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        total_loss = 0.0
    
        for i in range(num_splits):
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            start_idx = i * batch_size
            end_idx = min((i + 1) * batch_size, src_data.shape[0])
        
            src_batch = src_data[start_idx:end_idx]
            tgt_batch = tgt_data[start_idx:end_idx]
        
            output = transformer(src_batch, tgt_batch[:, :-1])

            loss = criterion(output.contiguous().view(-1, tgt_vocab_size), tgt_batch[:, 1:].contiguous().view(-1))
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
        
            total_loss += loss.item()
            
        if loss < best_loss:
            best_loss = loss
            torch.save(transformer.state_dict(), best_model_params_path)
    
        print(f"Epoch: {epoch+1}, Loss: {total_loss / num_splits}")
        
    transformer.load_state_dict(torch.load(best_model_params_path))

torch.save(transformer, "path.pth")
```

But when trying to interact with the generated model and get it to return an output it does not seem to work

the closest I have gotten to an actual solution was running the following code

```
model = torch.load("filepath.pth")

num_weights = sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters())
print("The model has {} weights.".format(num_weights))

enctype = "cl100k_base"
encoding = tiktoken.get_encoding(enctype)

input = torch.tensor(encoding.encode("AACS"))

output = model(input, input[:, :-1])

print(encoding.decode(output))
```

The transformer class above was copy pasted into the file as well otherwise the code would refuse to work at all, the current error I am getting with this code is

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "filepath.py", line 164, in <module>
 output = model(input, input[:, :-1])
IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 1
```

I also tried a modified version of the code which I dont have anymore but it was similar to the code above which resulted in the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filepath.py", line 164, in <module>
    output = model(input, input)
  File "filepath.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "filepath.py", line 138, in forward
    src_mask, tgt_mask = self.generate_mask(src.to('cuda'), tgt.to('cuda'))
  File "filepath.py", line 131, in generate_mask
    seq_length = -tgt.size(1)
IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)
```

Comment: Check the dimension of `input`. The error says it has only 1 dimension, but your code attempts to index 2 dimensions.